# The use of recursion in merge sort for python

Tags: python, recursion, mergesort

I am learning merge sort in python, and I am a little confused by the implementation of the following program. According to my understanding, when `mergeSort ([3,1], compare)` is implemented, it splits into `mergeSort([3], compare)` and `mergeSort([1], compare)`. and then `merge([3],[1], compare)` should be called, so that the `print` statement should be `left = [1,3]`, but the program actually prints out `left = [3,1]`, same for other `print` statements, why? Thank you very much.

```
def merge(left, right, compare):
    """Assumes left and right are sorted lists and compare defines an ordering
       on the elements.
       Returns a new sorted (by compare list containing the same elements as
       (left + right) would contain."""
    result = []
    i,j = 0, 0
    while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
        if compare(left[i], right[j]):
            result.append(left[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j += 1
    while (i < len(left)):
        result.append(left[i])
        i += 1
    while (j < len(right)):
        result.append(right[j])
        j += 1
    return result

import operator

def mergeSort(L, compare = operator.lt):
    """Assumes L is a list, compare defines an ordering on elements of L
       Returns a new sorted list containing the same elements as L"""
    if len(L) < 2:
        return L[:]
    else:
        middle = len(L)//2
        print "middle =", middle
        left = mergeSort(L[:middle], compare)
        print "left = ", L[:middle]
        right = mergeSort(L[middle:], compare)
        print "right = ", L[middle:]
        return merge(left, right, compare)
```

---

```
>>> L = [3,1,2,5,4,9,6,7,8]
>>> mergeSort(L, compare = operator.lt)
middle = 4
middle = 2
middle = 1
left =  [3]
right =  [1]
left =  [3, 1]
middle = 1
left =  [2]
right =  [5]
right =  [2, 5]
left =  [3, 1, 2, 5]
middle = 2
middle = 1
left =  [4]
right =  [9]
left =  [4, 9]
middle = 1
left =  [6]
middle = 1
left =  [7]
right =  [8]
right =  [7, 8]
right =  [6, 7, 8]
right =  [4, 9, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are absolutely right. Sorting doesn't affect the list L at all, it creates a new list, and what I am doing is just printing from the old L list. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code prints `L` as it is being recursively split apart. It doesn't actually print the result of any merges. You can see the result of each merge by changing the line

```
return merge(left, right, compare)
```

to

```
merged = merge(left, right, compare)
print "merged = ", merged
return merged
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
    print "left = ", L[:middle] # content of L before sorting
```

Replace this line and other analogous `print` statements with:

```
    print "left = ", left # actual result of mergeSort
```

Comment: Oh yeah, this is probably a better way to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

```
left = mergeSort(L[:middle], compare)
print "left = ", left
right = mergeSort(L[middle:], compare)
print "right = ", right
```

This should work.